# Use the recursion tree method to determine an asymptotic upper bound for solution of the following recurrence:

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, upper-lower-bounds

> $$T(n) = 2T\left(\frac n4\right) + n$$
>   Use the substitution method to verify the upper bound found.

My recursion tree looks like this:

[image: Recursion tree]

I got that the total Row sum is a geometric sequence and is equal to $n(1 + \dfrac12 + \dfrac14 + \dfrac18 + \cdots) = 2n$

Substitution method:

[image: Substitution Method]

**Am I doing this right? Is everything correct?  Is $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Why are you mixing the recursion tree method with the substitution method?
$$T(n) = 2T\left(\frac n4\right) + n$$
This means that the height of the tree is $\log_4 n$ and the width of the tree is $2^{\log_4 n} =\sqrt{n}$. Assuming $T(1)$ takes constant time $k$, $$\begin{align}T(n) = k\cdot\sqrt{n} + \sum_{i = 0}^{\log_4{n}}\frac n{2^i} = k\cdot\sqrt{n} + n\cdot\sum_{i = 0}^{\log_4{n}}\frac 1{2^i} &= k\cdot\sqrt{n} + n\left(2 - \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\ &= k\cdot\sqrt{n} + 2n - \sqrt{n} \\ &= (k -
 1)\sqrt{n} + 2n\end{align}$$
Since $n > \sqrt{n}$, $T(n)$ is $\Theta(n)$.

You can use the Master method (case III) for this, too.

Comment: Now I get this, thank you! But should I get the same result while doing the substitution method?

Comment: You should get the same result regardless of what method you use.

Comment: So what is wrong with my substitution method? Still cannot get it right.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, why are you mixing recursion tree method with the substitution method? Also, what are you assuming in substitution method?

Comment: In the question it is said to also use the Substitution Method for verifying the upper bound that I have already found using the recursion tree. 
Since T(n) is Θ(n), so I should assume T(n) <= cn and prove by Induction?

Comment: I think you are required to find the bound for $T(n)$ using both recursion tree method and substitution method and compare your answers. The key is 'verifying the upper bound already found using the recursion tree'. You have not yet found the upper bound in your attempt using the recursion tree method.

Comment: How should I continue to find the upper bound in the recursion tree?

Comment: Let $f_1(n) = \sqrt{n}$ and $f_2(n) = n$. Check to see which of these make the result of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T(n)}{f(n)}$ constant, where $T(n)$ is what I calculated in my answer, and $f(n)$ is one of $f_1(n)$ and $f_2(n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!